# Webservice endpoint with hook_services_resources()

Tags: 7, hooks, services

I've stumbled upon some limitations of the services module. I wanted to create the following endpoints:

```
public/events/
public/events/categories
public/events/resources
public/blogs/
```

I wanted to place all the above under a single endpoint with path "public/".
However, in the hook_services_resources the following is invalid:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_services_resources().
*/
function kw_api_services_resources() {
  $service_resources = 
   'event/categories' => array(
      'operations' => array(
        'index' => array(
```

I ended up using two endpoints public/events and public/blogs. Is there a way to get around this? Meaning to user deeper than 1 level URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Example from the module itself, the child is defined in the relationships:

```
'events' => array(
  'operations' => array(
    'retrieve' => array(
      'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/node_resource'),
      'callback' => '_node_resource_retrieve',
      'args' => array(
        array(
          'name' => 'nid',
          'optional' => FALSE,
          'source' => array('path' => 0),
          'type' => 'int',
          'description' => 'The nid of the node to get',
        ),
      ),
      'access callback' => '_node_resource_access',
      'access arguments' => array('view'),
      'access arguments append' => TRUE,
    ),
    'create' => array(
      'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/node_resource'),
      'callback' => '_node_resource_create',
      'args' => array(
        array(
          'name' => 'node',
          'optional' => FALSE,
          'source' => 'data',
          'description' => 'The node data to create',
          'type' => 'array',
        ),
      ),
      'access callback' => '_node_resource_access',
      'access arguments' => array('create'),
      'access arguments append' => TRUE,
    ),
    'update' => array(
      'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/node_resource'),
      'callback' => '_node_resource_update',
      'args' => array(
        array(
          'name' => 'nid',
          'optional' => FALSE,
          'source' => array('path' => 0),
          'type' => 'int',
          'description' => 'The nid of the node to get',
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'node',
          'optional' => FALSE,
          'source' => 'data',
          'description' => 'The node data to update',
          'type' => 'array',
        ),
      ),
      'access callback' => '_node_resource_access',
      'access arguments' => array('update'),
      'access arguments append' => TRUE,
    ),
    'delete' => array(
      'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/node_resource'),
      'callback' => '_node_resource_delete',
      'args' => array(
        array(
          'name' => 'nid',
          'optional' => FALSE,
          'source' => array('path' => 0),
          'type' => 'int',
        ),
      ),
      'access callback' => '_node_resource_access',
      'access arguments' => array('delete'),
      'access arguments append' => TRUE,
    ),
    'index' => array(
      'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/node_resource'),
      'callback' => '_node_resource_index',
      'args' => array(
        array(
          'name' => 'page',
          'optional' => TRUE,
          'type' => 'int',
          'description' => 'The zero-based index of the page to get, defaults to 0.',
          'default value' => 0,
          'source' => array('param' => 'page'),
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'fields',
          'optional' => TRUE,
          'type' => 'string',
          'description' => 'The fields to get.',
          'default value' => '*',
          'source' => array('param' => 'fields'),
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'parameters',
          'optional' => TRUE,
          'type' => 'array',
          'description' => 'Parameters array',
          'default value' => array(),
          'source' => array('param' => 'parameters'),
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'pagesize',
          'optional' => TRUE,
          'type' => 'int',
          'description' => 'Number of records to get per page.',
          'default value' => variable_get('services_node_index_page_size', 20),
          'source' => array('param' => 'pagesize'),
        ),
      ),
      'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    ),
  ),
  'targeted_actions' => array(
    'attach_file' => array(
      'help' => 'Upload and attach file(s) to a node. POST multipart/form-data to node/123/attach_file',
      'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/node_resource'),
      'callback' => '_node_resource_attach_file',
      'access callback' => '_node_resource_access',
      'access arguments' => array('update'),
      'access arguments append' => TRUE,
      'args' => array(
        array(
          'name' => 'nid',
          'optional' => FALSE,
          'source' => array('path' => 0),
          'type' => 'int',
          'description' => 'The nid of the node to attach a file to',
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'field_name',
          'optional' => FALSE,
          'source' => array('data' => 'field_name'),
          'description' => 'The file parameters',
          'type' => 'string',
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'attach',
          'optional' => TRUE,
          'source' => array('data' => 'attach'),
          'description' => 'Attach the file(s) to the node. If FALSE, this clears ALL files attached, and attaches the files',
          'type' => 'int',
          'default value' => TRUE,
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'field_values',
          'optional' => TRUE,
          'source' => array('data' => 'field_values'),
          'description' => 'The extra field values',
          'type' => 'array',
          'default value' => array(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'relationships' => array(
    'resources' => array(
      'file' => array('type' => 'inc', 'module' => 'services', 'name' => 'resources/node_resource'),
      'help'   => t('This method returns files associated with a node.'),
      'access callback' => '_node_resource_access',
      'access arguments' => array('view'),
      'access arguments append' => TRUE,
      'callback' => '_node_resource_load_node_files',
      'args'     => array(
        array(
          'name' => 'nid',
          'optional' => FALSE,
          'source' => array('path' => 0),
          'type' => 'int',
          'description' => 'The nid of the node whose files we are getting',
        ),
        array(
          'name' => 'file_contents',
          'type' => 'int',
          'description'  => t('To return file contents or not.'),
          'source' => array('path' => 2),
          'optional' => TRUE,
          'default value' => TRUE,
        ),
        array(
          'name'         => 'image_styles',
          'type'         => 'int',
          'description'  => t('To return image styles or not.'),
          'source'       => array('path' => 3),
          'optional'     => TRUE,
          'default value' => FALSE,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```